# Proving the jacobian of the inverse of stereographic projection is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let the inverse of the stereographic projection be $\pi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{(0,0,\dots,0,1)\}$

$\pi^{-1}(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n) = \left( \dfrac{2y_1}{||y||^2+1},\dfrac{2y_2}{||y||^2+1}, \dots, \dfrac{||y||^2-1}{||y||^2+1}\right)$

I calculated the jacobian, and it is given by:

$\mathcal{d}\pi^{-1}(y_1,\dots,y_n) = \frac{1}{\left( ||y||^2 + 1 \right)^{2}} \left[ \begin{matrix}
  \ 2 \left( ||y||^2 + 1 \right) - 4 y_{1}^2 & - 2 y_{1} y_{2} & \cdots & - 2 y_{1} y_{n} \\
  - 2 y_{1} y_{2} & 2 \left( ||y||^2 + 1 \right) - 4 y_{2}^2 & \cdots & - 2 y_{2} y_{n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  - 2 y_{1} y_{n} & - 2 y_{2} y_{n} & \cdots & 2 \left( ||y||^2 + 1 \right) - 4 y_{n}^2\  \\
  4 y_{1} & 4 y_{2} & \cdots & 4 y_{n}\  \\
 \end{matrix} \right]$

I want to prove this matrix is injective for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried row-reducing, but got some big expressions inside the matrix that I don't know how to handle.

My aim is precisely to prove **this matrix is injective**, because I want to prove that $\pi^{-1}$ is a parametrization in this way, not using more sophisticated techniques of differential geometry.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients of the off-diagonal entries on the first $n$ rows are incorrect. They should be $-4$ rather than $-2$: when $i\ne j$,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\frac{2y_i}{\|y\|^2+1}
=\frac{-2y_i}{(\|y\|^2+1)^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} (\|y\|^2+1)
=\frac{-4y_iy_j}{(\|y\|^2+1)^2}.
$$
Therefore, if you add $y_i$ times the last row to the $i$-row, the matrix becomes
$$
\frac{1}{(\|y\|^2+1)^2}\pmatrix{2(\|y\|^2+1)I\\ 4y^T},
$$
which clearly has full column rank.

Answer (score 1):

The stereographic projection map $\pi:\Bbb{S}^n\setminus\{(0,\dots, 1)\}\to \Bbb{R}^n$ can be extended to $\sigma:\Bbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{x\in\Bbb{R}^{n+1}| \, \, 1-x_{n+1} \neq 0\} \to \Bbb{R}^n$ given by
\begin{align}
\sigma(x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}) &= \left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_{n+1}}, \dots, \frac{x_n}{1-x_{n+1}}\right)
\end{align}
In other words, using the same formula, we can extend $\pi$ to a map $\sigma$ defined on an open subset of Euclidean space. Then, it's clear that $\sigma \circ \pi^{-1}:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ is just the identity map. Hence, for any $y\in\Bbb{R}^n$, we have by the chain rule (which we can apply since the maps $\sigma$ and $\pi^{-1}$ are differentiable functions (in the usual sense) between open subsets of Euclidean spaces)
\begin{align}
d\sigma_{\pi^{-1}(y)} \circ d(\pi^{-1})_y &= \text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}
\end{align}
It follows that $d(\pi^{-1})_y:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ is injective.